# What is the name of a plot of - log 10 of p values in multiple testing?

Tags: data-visualization, multiple-comparisons

Under the null, the p-value is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. Taking the negative of the log base 10 of many such p-values should follow an exponential distribution. You can show quantiles of their distribution under the null, but more importantly, logging them makes large differences very compelling. I can't remember the name of such a plot though:

[image]

```
## example R code
x <- replicate(100, rnorm(10), simplify=FALSE)
y <- replicate(100, rnorm(10), simplify=FALSE)

lm.sig <- function(x, y) {
  coef(summary(lm(y ~ x)))[2, 4]
}

sigs <- mapply(lm.sig, x, y)

plot(-log(sigs, base=10), type='h', xlab='Comparison Index', ylab='-log p value')
abline(h=-log(0.05, base=10), lty=2)
legend('topleft', lty=2, 'Nominal 0.05 error rate')
```

Comment: I don't know of a specific name of such a plot (though I'd bet it has probably been called by a couple of names before). I'd be inclined to put actual probabilities on the plot (or at the least, include them on the right side).

Comment: Agreed. That would be my mistake. The y-axis could be better labeled to represent the log-scale. The problem with presenting untransformed p-values is that 0.05 doesn't look much different from 0.01, nor 0.01 from 0.0001. Complementary log transformations allow such values to "pop".

Comment: I'm not sure if we misunderstand each other or it's just my own lack of comprehension of part of your response. I have no problem with the use of a log-scale, merely the value labels on the axis. I find it much easier to interpret "0.005" than "-2.3". I'm merely suggesting the use of tick marks and labels for $p$ rather than $\log_{10}p$\*, or at least the use of two axes. $\quad\quad$\*(while keeping the plot essentially unchanged -- well, I would also plot points rather than lines; what does the length of the line-segment mean on the plot?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geneticists call this a "Manhattan plot". Usually the bars are thicker, with no gap in between, so it looks (sort of kind of) like the New York skyline.

Comment: That's right! I kept thinking "Metropolis" plot, as I knew there was some relationship to a city and the shape of the figure.

Answer (score 3):

A plot of vertical lines is often called a "Needle Plot". See [Graphics with R](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/120/Notes/ch03.pdf) (section 3.7.3) or [SAS doc](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/62603/HTML/default/viewer.htm#needle-stmt.htm).

Normally there is a shared baseline for the needles, making it conceptually like a bar chart. Your code suggests a baseline of 0 `segments(seq(sigs), 0, seq(sigs), -log(sigs, base=10))`, but your image looks more like lines centered at 0, `segments(seq(sigs), log(sigs, base=10), seq(sigs), -log(sigs, base=10))`.

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to `type='h'` for generating verticle line (e.g. needle plots). However, Manhattan, as Harvey indicated, is the term for multiple testing and p-value context specifically.